# Alternate heat recovery systems upstairs and downstairs

Tags: exhaust-fan, ventilation

[image: air flow]I'm looking to increase the ventilation in my house by a little bit to compensate for measures we're using to reduce unintentional ventilation (blocking draughts). I don't need and can't afford a super all over the house solution.

As a middle ground I was thinking putting an inward flow heat recovery fan at the bottom of my stairs above my front door then at the top of the stairs in the bathroom an outward flow heat recovery fan. I'd install a plastic vent on the bathroom door to allow continuous air flow. The bathroom door would be the only barrier between the two heat recovery systems. My question is, would this be effective? Or would the difference in height and distance between the fans make it ineffective? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is "heat recovery?"

Comment: It’s a well-known concept. If you aren’t familiar with it, do some research.

Comment: @nobody Heusmann is asking about two separate, one-way flow heat recovery systems as OP is describing. News of these has not reached my desk and Google seems to be failing me... do enlighten us!

Comment: One example of many, having sorted out that they are actually of the "flow-reversing" type.: https://ventilation-system.com/series/reversible-heat-and-energy-recovery-ventilator-solo

Answer (score 1):

**Heat Recovery Ventilators** flow in two directions at the same location, and exchange heat between the airstreams (via a heat exchanger) going out and in. Of course the terminal ducts are (or should be) arranged so that the airstreams are not short-circuited, despite the "one location" aspect.

A fan blowing out one place and a fan blowing in someplace else do not constitute a heat recovery fan in either location, without some complex and expensive plumbing of heat exchangers between them (pretty much never done that way due to cost, complexity, etc.)

You could put a heat recovery fan in one or both of the locations, but that would not be what you have drawn.

A DIY HRV can be constructed by using concentric ducts [*i.e.* blow air out a 4" duct that's inside a 6" duct sucking in, or out a 6" duct inside an 8" duct sucking in] rather than a manufactured heat exchanger, if you have space to do that - the main advantage of a commercial HRV is that it's more compact, but that comes with a high price tag.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was being super stupid when I posted this and I got it wrong (I forgot that heat recovery requires an inward flow to exchange heat with an outward flow). What the system actually does is work in tandem. Basically for 70 seconds one blows in, one blows out, then for the next 70 seconds they reverse so the pressure differential reverses every 70 seconds. What I'm not sure of is if the distance between the two is too great for them to actually work effectively together. To be honest just using two isolated units might be enough but I'd like them to work together

Comment: Right - *that type* works by storing heat in a metallic or ceramic core and reversing the fan. Reviews I've see are somewhat mixed, as the typical fans can be overwhelmed by wind pressure in some conditions. Coordinating them to work in tandem is fairly normal. Not clear that you really want the intake air to hit the other in exhaust mode. The point is to bring in some fresh air and exhaust some stale air with each cycle, with considerable mixing taking place.

Comment: A concentric-duct heat exchanger would have to be *rather long* to be effective.  And insulated I would think.

Comment: @SoyCapitan you'd need those in pairs. You can't pull a vacuum on a house unless it's built like a warship (refresh your knife-edge seals every 10 years, not like museum ships) and then it would be uninhabitable from your eardrums popping every minute.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is just a powered return duct, not heat recovery ?which refers to a specific device that *reduces* heat flow while moving air).

If you think too much hot air is moving up the stairwell, and you don't want to close doors or create some other physical barrier to reduce that circulation, a powered return isn't an awful idea. It only needs one fan, though, unless you are trying to do complicated things with multiple inlets and outlets.

I've experimented with that in my own house, since I seemed to be getting a lot of convective flow since switching to the heat pump. (The radiators included one at the base of the stairs specifically to heat the stairwell.) Results of the experiment were inconclusive, which makes me hesitate to say go ahead.

I would suggest instead that, as I did, you start with an experimental setup before opening any walls. I got a blower and a length of flexible duct, temporarily mounted the blower high above the top of the staircase, and just ran the duct down the stairwell, then found someplace to run an extension cord to power the blower. That let me try out the idea for a total investment of about US$40. It isn't *pretty*, but it will give you some sense of whether this is worth doing or the doors are a better idea after all.

One thing the test pointed out was that wherever you put the fan, there may be a noise issue depending how n how much air you want to move, the fan's design, and how you mount it.

So if you want to try it, I would suggest you try a cheap test setup and let that tell you whether it is worth doing more. You may find that, ugly as it is, the cheap solution is acceptable..  or you may decide you'd rather close doors.

Comment: When dome houses were in fashion, it was a common suggestion to add a fan with a return up at the top of the dome and an exhaust down at the bottom, usually at whatever mechanical chase you ran to the second floor. It made a significant difference in comfort by reducing the stratification of air within the structure. The same idea can work in more conventional construction as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was being a bit dumb and got my initial question wrong. What my suggested setup would do is each fan would switch directions every 70 seconds in order to exchange heat with incoming and outgoing air, but they'd be synced so while one is blowing in, the other would always blow out and vice versa. I guess what I want to know is if two relatively small fans so far apart would draw enough air to actually create an effective flow. It's a good idea to test with a jury rigged system though with similar sized fans to test, thanks

Comment: Unless the duct is elastic or the fans are underpowered, you don't need two fans to do that, just one reversable fan. And I don't think this would have better results than simply running the duct in the appropriate direction to offset convection, downward in winter and upward in summer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock up a heat recovery system with string and tape.   If you don't want to spend the money on one right now, your best option is to plug up the drafts, open windows when it's nice out, and forgo ventilation when the outside temperature is extreme.

The system in your diagram is not a heat recovery system.  It's an effective way to cool your house with outside air on a cool evening after a hot day.  Arrange the openings in your house so that a fan forces hot air out the top and sucks cold air in the bottom. But to be very effective you want to open all downstairs windows, not just one by the door, and put a very powerful fan on the exhaust, not a typical bathroom fan.

Another cheap trick, if you have forced air heating or air conditioning, is to run the fan constantly or more frequently to circulate the air between upstairs and downstairs.  Some thermostats have a "Circulate" setting to do that, which runs the fan for something like 15 minutes per hour even if heat or cool is not demanded.

Comment: Thank you. As per my comment above I was mistaken and actually each fan would reverse every 70 seconds but work in sync so while one is in exhaust mode, the other would be drawing in air then vice versa on the next 70 second cycle. This allows heat exchange as they can be used in isolation, but I'm curious to test if it would create enough of a pressure differential to create an actual flow or if the fans are too small/far apart

Comment: The "cheap trick" is what I'm proposing and what I prototyped.